# How to transform one-character into two-character word element using bash text processing commands?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have many scripts like this in a folder:

```
INSERT INTO fv_xml_binary_adim VALUES (1, '<FeatureVector><feature>project</feature><feature>w</feature><feature>focus</feature><feature>d</feature><feature>new</feature><feature>cut</feature><feature>tool</feature><feature>design</feature><feature>allow</feature><feature>increas</feature><feature>high</feature><feature>speed</feature><feature>machin</feature><feature>hsm</feature><feature>product</feature></FeatureVector>');
```

I want to take one-character elements and transform them into a two-characters elements. 
I want to transform the command above into:

```
INSERT INTO fv_xml_binary_adim VALUES (1, '<FeatureVector><feature>project</feature><feature>w0</feature><feature>focus</feature><feature>d0</feature><feature>new</feature><feature>cut</feature><feature>tool</feature><feature>design</feature><feature>allow</feature><feature>increas</feature><feature>high</feature><feature>speed</feature><feature>machin</feature><feature>hsm</feature><feature>product</feature></FeatureVector>');
```

How can I make it using sed or other bash text processing command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/>(.)</>\10</g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` you could use:

```
sed 's/>\([a-z]\)</>\10</g'
```

This would transform `>w<` into `>w0<`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Regex with sed

`sed -i -E "s%(feature>)([a-z]{1})(</feature)%\1\20\3%g" file`